# JavaFX Application Packaging example needed

Tags: java, javafx

I have created a simple application for the maintainance of the Contact List.
As I'm a novice to JavaFX, I just want to know about the packaging option.
I want to package the app as StandAlone application where package includes JRE files needed for running the app.

I found this on JavaFX documentation.
[Standalone application Packaging](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#BCGHAHII)

But not getting how to do it?
An example would be really helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that you are looking to build a Windows standalone application, so you will first need to install [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) to build the msi and [Inno](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php) to build the exe. You will also need to have ant configured. This example assumes that your directory layout is as follows:

```
+---classes
+---dist
+---lib
```

where 'classes' contains the compiled .class files, and the resources that your application needs, 'lib' contains the dependencies jar files, and 'dist' is the target folder which wil contain the application jar file once packed. To pack the application create a build.xml file in the same directory containing:

```
<project name="JavaFXSample" default="default" basedir="."
         xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
    <target name="default">
        <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"      
                uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
                classpath="<here goes the path to java home>/lib/ant-javafx.jar"/>    

        <fx:jar destfile="dist/example.jar">

        <fx:application name="Sample JavaFX application" mainClass="me.App"/>

        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="lib/*.jar"/>
        </fx:resources>

        <fileset dir="classes"/>
        </fx:jar>        
    </target>      
</project>
```

this will create an 'example.jar' file in the dist folder. Now you should check that the 'javafxpackager' tool is included in your path and then call:

```
javafxpackager -deploy -native -outdir packages -outfile Example -srcdir dist -srcfiles example.jar -appclass <your main class> -name "Example" -title "JavaFX Example demo"
```

this will create a layout containing the standalone files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Problem has been solved.
I was actually not getting where I have to insert that code.
Reading your reply, got me there.
Thanks once again :)